# How etcd cluster data is read and synchronized under k8s clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

To build a highly available `k8s` cluster, you need to build an `etcd` cluster, which I see in the official `k8s` documentation.

[Each control plane node creates a local etcd member and this etcd member communicates only with the kube-apiserver of this node. The same applies to the local kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler instances.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology)

That is, `kube-apiservice` only communicates with `etcd` of its own node, can we understand that reads and writes happen on `etcd` of the same node,

But when I was studying `etcd`, I was told that the clients in the `etcd` cluster read data through `Follower` and write data through `Leader`.

```bash
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/kubescape]
└─$ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl  --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379  --cert="/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt"  --key="/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key"  --cacert="/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt" endpoint status --cluster  -w table
+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|          ENDPOINT           |        ID        | VERSION | DB SIZE | IS LEADER | RAFT TERM | RAFT INDEX |
+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| https://192.168.26.100:2379 |  ee392e5273e89e2 |   3.5.4 |   37 MB |     false |       100 |    3152364 |
| https://192.168.26.102:2379 | 11486647d7f3a17b |   3.5.4 |   36 MB |     false |       100 |    3152364 |
| https://192.168.26.101:2379 | e00e3877df8f76f4 |   3.5.4 |   36 MB |      true |       100 |    3152364 |
+-----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/kubescape]
└─$
```

In fact, there is only one `Leader` in the cluster. Does this read/write separation of `etcd` clusters apply to `k8s`?

I understand that this is contradictory to what is said above. I would like to know how `etcd` reads and writes in a `k8s` cluster.

---

I know very little about `etcd`, thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In fact, there is only one Leader in the cluster. Does this read/write separation of etcd clusters apply to Kubernetes?

Yes. In an etc cluster, there is only one leader that does the writes. But etcd internally forwards all requests that needs *consensus* (e.g. writes) to the *leader*, so the client application (Kubernetes in our case) does not need to know what etcd node is the leader.

From [etcd FAQ](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/):

> **Do clients have to send requests to the etcd leader?**

> Raft is leader-based; the leader handles all client requests which need cluster consensus. However, the client does not need to know which node is the leader. Any request that requires consensus sent to a follower is automatically forwarded to the leader. Requests that do not require consensus (e.g., serialized reads) can be processed by any cluster member.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient answer, English is not good, I am using the translation tool